# How can I detect the first instance of a command-line Dart program to start?

Tags: dart

I want to run multiple instances of a program from the command-line and I need to know which is the first to start - I need to synchronize them. I also need to know that subsequent instances are not the first. Currently I ask the operator if this is the first-instance, however I would prefer to not have to do that.

Can anyone suggest a better way to handle that situation.

Comment: More a workaround idea: Open a local network port on the first instance (with a fixed port number). If a second instance is started it can't use that port, but could connect to the first instance for communication.

Comment: Thanks "Fox 32" I'll look at that. I think eventually, I need to look at spawning the "sub" processes, however that is outside the scope of the question, and I haven't looked at that yet. I'll look into your answer as a solution to the immediate problem.

Comment: That appears to work well, and also solves a problem where a process could be started as the "sole" process where it had to be assumed that it was the first process.

Comment: Fox32 Why don't you post that as a solution, because it solves that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting if a instance of a program is the first instant is often done using a mutex. But Dart don't have any syncronisation methods build in.

An alternative approach would be using a network port on the loopback interface. Choose a fixed port, if a instance is started, check if you can listen on the port. If the port is not available, another instance is already running.

As a positive side effect you can use the connection to communicate between the instances of your application.